# Can't stop MySQL service (running but not found)

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, docker

I have MySQL server running in docker `FROM ubuntu/mysql:8.0-22.04_beta`

I am trying to stop the service

```
$> /etc/init.d/mysql stop
bash: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory

$> service stop mysqld
stop: unrecognized service

$> service stop mysql 
stop: unrecognized service

$> systemctl stop mysqld
ERROR:systemctl:Unit mysqld.service could not be found.

$> systemctl stop mysql 
ERROR:systemctl:Unit mysql.service could not be found.

$> ps -aux | grep sql
mysql         35  0.7  1.2 2532224 419596 ?      Sl   14:11   0:01 mysqld
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: are you sure it is running as a service and not in a standalone version?